# How to write a custom textbox in WPF with other components "glued" on it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have been for 2 days now trying to develop my own WPF textbox for no avail.

My initial try was inheriting from a control and then adding a template with all the stuff I wanted (a border and an asterisk in the outside).

Generic.xaml file:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BdlTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:BdlTextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="Tbl" Text="*" Foreground="Red" FontSize="15" Margin="0,-4,0,0"
                                   Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:BdlTextBox}},
                            Path=IsRequired, Converter={StaticResource myBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Bg" Fill="Red" Opacity="0"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Tb" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimation">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bg" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="2x" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Bg" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" BeginTime="0:0:2"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=HasValidationError}" Value="True" >
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Name="flash" Storyboard="{StaticResource flashAnimation}" />
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="flash"/>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=HasValidationError}" Value="False" >
                        <Setter TargetName="Bg" Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is: I cannot use the control as a Textbox (the reason is obvious). I can't even properly use the Text property. So I was wondering what could be done to solve this problem.

Dependency Properties are also a problem. I have tried to "clone" the Text property from the Textbox "Tb", but failed too.

Comment: I did not try it but your template should work just instead of `<TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Tb" Margin="1,1,1,1"/>` use `<ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>`. Note it must be named like that, And also where you use `RelativeSource Self` try using `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`

Comment: It looks like it works. But now my textbox is so small I can't even see it. It doesn't fill its parent control anymore.
What should I do?

Comment: Just figured out that I was missing `Grid.Column="1"` on the new component.
But now I have noticed a new problem: I don't have the textbox background anymore! How can I inherit the default template?

Comment: then set background to something like `<Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>

Comment: This only artificially adds a background, but other traits of a Textbox such as the border are still missing...

Comment: You need to add them in similar way. You've changed the `Template` so you're building looks of your control from scratch. If you don't add it it won't have it.